# Sorting Data in R by two columns but alternating each row

Tags: r, sorting, tidyverse

I am trying to determine the number of times that x or y individuals (represented by a unique number each) are dominant to each other. I have used count to summarize the data:

```
Dominance1<-count(Dominance, c('Dominant', 'Subordinate'))
```

And the data look like this:

```
 >     Dominant Subordinate freq
            5           9   14
            5          10    9
            5          11    4
            5          15    7
            5          18   14
            5          22    6
            5          24    9
            5          26    5
            5          40    8
            5          43    5
            9          10    4
            9          11    6
            9          15    1
            9          18    7
            9          22   14
            9          24    6
            9          25    7
           10          15    1
           10          18    1
           10          22    2
           10          40    1
           10          43    1
           10          75    4
```

... and so on (All of the unique IDs are: 5,9, 10, 11, 80, 15, 75,18,85,22,82,24,25,26,86,68,79,83,81,77,91,40,87,43,78... total dataset is 321 rows of the different relationships observed between these IDs and the frequency of observations).

But I need to also look at how many times '9' was dominant when '5' was subordinate, side by side. Is it possible to order so that the data looks like this?

```
 >     Dominant Subordinate freq
          5          9       14
          9          5        0
          5          11       4
          11         5        7
```

Currently it's just in order based on the 'Dominant' column. Is there a way to alternate like I showed above so that I can see how often x is dominant to y and compare to how often y is dominant to x lined up like that?

Here is the full dataset:

```
Dom Sub freq
5   9   14
5   10  9
5   11  4
5   15  7
5   18  14
5   22  6
5   24  9
5   26  5
5   40  8
5   43  5
5   75  15
5   77  10
5   78  10
5   80  3
5   81  2
5   82  12
5   83  11
5   85  8
5   87  11
5   91  16
9   10  4
9   11  6
9   15  1
9   18  7
9   22  14
9   24  6
9   25  7
9   26  6
9   40  12
9   43  8
9   75  10
9   77  1
9   79  1
9   80  4
9   82  20
9   85  9
9   87  7
9   91  4
10  15  1
10  18  1
10  22  2
10  40  1
10  43  1
10  75  4
10  78  1
10  79  4
10  80  3
10  81  1
10  87  1
11  10  2
11  26  1
11  40  1
11  43  3
11  77  1
11  80  5
11  85  1
15  18  2
15  22  1
15  43  1
15  77  1
15  78  1
15  79  2
15  81  1
15  83  2
15  85  2
15  87  2
15  91  2
18  22  2
18  24  1
18  78  2
18  79  1
18  80  4
22  24  2
22  40  1
24  10  1
24  18  1
24  22  7
24  26  11
24  75  1
24  78  3
24  79  8
24  81  11
24  83  5
24  86  8
24  91  13
25  5   3
25  9   1
25  10  3
25  11  3
25  15  2
25  18  1
25  22  6
25  24  5
25  26  3
25  40  5
25  43  8
25  75  3
25  77  7
25  78  5
25  79  5
25  80  3
25  81  2
25  82  6
25  83  5
25  85  2
25  87  6
25  91  3
26  10  3
26  11  8
26  18  5
26  22  1
26  40  9
26  43  5
26  77  1
26  78  7
26  80  5
26  83  1
26  85  3
26  91  1
40  10  1
40  15  1
40  22  4
40  25  1
40  75  1
40  80  1
40  81  1
40  83  1
40  85  1
40  87  2
40  91  1
43  18  2
43  22  2
43  24  7
43  40  4
43  75  3
43  77  2
43  79  2
43  80  3
43  82  1
68  5   15
68  9   41
68  10  3
68  11  5
68  15  6
68  18  9
68  22  12
68  24  8
68  25  14
68  26  1
68  40  8
68  43  10
68  75  6
68  77  9
68  78  3
68  79  6
68  80  3
68  81  3
68  82  5
68  83  5
68  85  12
68  86  9
68  87  9
68  91  4
75  10  1
75  15  1
75  18  2
75  22  4
75  24  2
75  26  2
75  40  3
75  77  1
75  78  6
75  79  6
75  80  6
75  81  1
75  82  2
75  87  7
77  5   1
77  15  1
77  18  7
77  22  2
77  24  1
77  40  4
77  78  8
77  79  2
77  80  4
77  81  7
77  82  1
77  85  5
77  87  3
78  10  3
78  11  1
78  15  1
78  18  1
78  40  2
78  43  1
78  83  2
78  86  2
79  5   4
79  9   20
79  15  1
79  18  1
79  26  4
79  68  1
79  75  1
79  77  1
79  78  2
79  80  1
79  81  4
79  82  10
79  83  9
79  85  4
79  91  15
80  22  2
80  43  1
80  78  2
81  5   14
81  9   20
81  10  2
81  18  8
81  22  11
81  25  3
81  26  4
81  43  1
81  68  1
81  75  4
81  77  1
81  78  4
81  79  3
81  80  11
81  82  13
81  83  13
81  85  1
81  86  3
81  87  1
81  91  16
82  10  4
82  15  4
82  18  1
82  22  1
82  24  3
82  26  2
82  40  7
82  43  3
82  77  5
82  78  2
82  80  4
82  83  3
82  85  2
82  87  4
83  9   2
83  10  4
83  11  3
83  15  7
83  18  2
83  22  2
83  25  2
83  26  5
83  43  3
83  68  1
83  75  3
83  77  7
83  78  5
83  80  2
83  81  1
83  82  2
83  85  1
83  87  9
83  91  4
85  10  2
85  11  2
85  15  1
85  18  1
85  22  2
85  26  1
85  40  2
85  43  6
85  75  4
85  78  1
85  79  2
85  80  2
86  5   9
86  9   6
86  10  5
86  11  6
86  15  5
86  18  5
86  22  9
86  25  22
86  26  6
86  40  3
86  43  12
86  68  1
86  75  16
86  77  4
86  78  4
86  79  9
86  80  8
86  82  16
86  83  6
86  85  6
86  87  5
86  91  12
87  10  1
87  77  1
87  80  4
87  85  1
91  10  4
91  11  3
91  18  5
91  22  1
91  24  1
91  26  2
91  40  1
91  43  1
91  75  3
91  77  4
91  80  2
91  82  9
91  85  8
91  87  8
```

Comment: Is the dataset bigger or is this the whole thing?

Comment: it's bigger. 321 rows.

Comment: Full dataset is there at the bottom now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for posting the full dataset! Updates below:

```
library(igraph)
Dom <- read.table("localcopyofdata.txt",header=TRUE)
g <- graph.data.frame(Dom[,1:2],directed=TRUE)
E(g)$weight <- as.numeric(Dom[,3])
```

This generates an `igraph` object with 321 connections that you can see by typing `g`. To do the sorting you want, we have to pull out the first half+1 of the vertices:

```
> vertices <- unique(V(g)[1:floor((length(unique(V(g)))/2)+1)])
+ 13/25 vertices, named, from c0101e5:
 [1] 5  9  10 11 15 18 22 24 25 26 40 43 68
```

(Actually, it wouldn't hurt if you did this for all vertices with `vertices <- unique(V(g)` -- you'd be able to look up connections by any node later.) Now that we know the vertices, we can apply a function to all of them that will pull out the matches in a way you can compare them. The command is:

```
lapply(vertices, function(x) E(g)[[inc(x)]])
```

And the output looks like this, with one group per node:

```
$`5`
+ 26/321 edges from c0101e5 (vertex names):
    tail head tid hid weight
1      5    9   1   2     14
2      5   10   1   3      9
3      5   11   1   4      4
4      5   15   1   5      7
5      5   18   1   6     14
6      5   22   1   7      6
7      5   24   1   8      9
8      5   26   1  10      5
9      5   40   1  11      8
10     5   43   1  12      5
11     5   75   1  14     15
12     5   77   1  15     10
13     5   78   1  16     10
14     5   80   1  18      3
15     5   81   1  19      2
16     5   82   1  20     12
17     5   83   1  21     11
18     5   85   1  22      8
19     5   87   1  24     11
20     5   91   1  25     16
86    25    5   9   1      3
140   68    5  13   1     15
178   77    5  15   1      1
199   79    5  17   1      4
217   81    5  19   1     14
282   86    5  23   1      9
```

If you do `results <- lapply(vertices, function(x) E(g)[[inc(x)]])` then you can call whatever node you want individually:

```
> results$'5'
+ 26/321 edges from c0101e5 (vertex names):
    tail head tid hid weight
1      5    9   1   2     14
2      5   10   1   3      9
3      5   11   1   4      4
... the rest are truncated
```

Now you can make a `dplyr`-able data frame from `results` (be sure to change the 13 to `length(results)` if you want to use this on another dataset):

```
step1 <- capture.output(for(n in 1:13) { for(j in n){print(results[[j]])} })
step2 <- step1[grep("^\\d",step1),drop=T]
step3 <- unlist(strsplit(step2,"\\s+")) # produces list of 1938 numbers
step4 <- as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(step3), ncol=6, byrow=TRUE), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
group <- cumsum(c(1, sign(diff(as.numeric(step4$V1)) < 0)))
step5 <- cbind(group,step4[,c(2,3,6)])
names(step5) <- c("Group","Dom","Sub","Weight")
```

Now you can do `dplyr` things with it like:

```
> step5 %>% filter(Group==1)
   Group Dom Sub Weight
1      1   5   9     14
2      1   5  10      9
3      1   5  11      4
4      1   5  15      7
5      1   5  18     14
6      1   5  22      6
... the rest is truncated
```

Hope this helps! There's got to be a much simpler way to solve this, but I like how representing it as a graph gives you the opportunity to visualize the connections (maybe not for your problem, but for other problems that I have).

Comment: Thank you! This is great! So I don't really understand what the +26/321 or +13/25 c0101e5 (vertex names) is for... 
I have: 

library(igraph)  ---
Dominance<-read.table("Dominance_Display_Counts.txt",header=TRUE) ---
g <- graph.data.frame(Dominance[,1:2],directed=TRUE) ---
E(g)$weight <- as.numeric(Dominance[,3]) ---
vertices <- unique(V(g)) ---


x<-lapply(vertices, function(x) E(g)[[inc(x)]]) ---

And it seems to have worked unless I am missing something? Also, how can I save this? igraph apparently can't be coerced to dataframe to save as .csv.

Comment: The +26/321... is just metadata from the igraph object. I've actually been trying to figure out a way to create a data frame out of this for the past hour or so... will let you know when I figure it out. This has become one of those puzzles that won't let me stop thinking about it.

Comment: Did you see the edits I made about an hour ago? Got the data into df format. Circuitous but effective.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! Why 13 though?

Comment: it's just length(results) -- I hardcoded it so the whole line would appear in the code window without having to scroll right. Fancy, I know

Answer (score 0):

The `summarise` and `group_by` functions in `dplyr` might be useful here:

```
library(dplyr)

# Creating some data for us to work with: 
x <- round(runif(n = 100, min = 0, max = 10))
y <- round(runif(n = 100, min = 0, max = 10))

df <- data.frame(x,y)

df %>% 
  group_by(x, y) %>%
  summarise(freq= n())
```

The frequency of each unique pair of x and y is produced in the 'freq' column

```
# A tibble: 65 x 3
# Groups:   x [?]
       x     y   freq
   <dbl> <dbl>  <int>
 1    0.    0.      1
 2    0.    2.      1
 3    0.    4.      1
 4    0.    5.      1
 5    0.    7.      1
 6    1.    2.      3
 7    1.    4.      2
 8    1.    5.      2
 9    1.    6.      2
10    1.    8.      1
# ... with 55 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you! I think that is what I was doing here: Dominance1<-count(Dominance, c('Dominant', 'Subordinate'))   So the data already has the frequency of each unique pair in the freq column... I just need to look at the frequency of "x" dominant to "y" next to the frequency of "y" dominant to "x" so that I can see which scenario happens more often. I need "x" to be dominant to "y" >3 times more than "y" is dominant to "x" in order to determine that "x" is in fact dominant. Is there a way to sort so that they line up like that? Or maybe there's another way to find that answer?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered representing this data as a graph to examine it? It may be useful if you're just trying to identify where the pairs are (not as useful if you want to do this programmatically). The data you provided doesn't have any mutuals so we can't pick any of them out here -- if they do exist, they will POP when you look at the graph. But, maybe this will be helpful:

```
library(igraph)
Dominance1 <- read.table("local copy of data",header=TRUE)
g <- graph.data.frame(Dominance1[,1:2],directed=TRUE)
E(g)$weight <- as.numeric(Dominance1[,3])
plot(g,edge.arrow.size=0.5,edge.curved=0.2,vertex.color="lightblue",
   vertex.size=22,layout=layout_on_grid,edge.color="black")
```

[image: Pair Identification]

You can add `edge.label=E(g)$weight` as an argument to `plot` if you want to see the weights on the graph.

You can find the nodes with reciprocals with `which(which_mutual(g)=="TRUE")` -- since there are no matches in the sample data, the output is boring, but when you run it on the full dataset it should pull out all your mutuals for you.

```
> E(g)[which(which_mutual(g)=="FALSE")]  # edges where there are no mutuals
+ 23/23 edges from 998a30d (vertex names):
 [1] 5 ->9  5 ->10 5 ->11 5 ->15 5 ->18 5 ->22 5 ->24 5 ->26 5 ->40 5 ->43 9 ->10 9 ->11
[13] 9 ->15 9 ->18 9 ->22 9 ->24 9 ->25 10->15 10->18 10->22 10->40 10->43 10->75

> E(g)[which(which_mutual(g)=="TRUE")]  # edges where there ARE mutuals
+ 0/23 edges from 998a30d (vertex names):
```

I know this is kind of a sideways approach to your problem, but hope it's maybe a little useful!

Comment: Thank you! I do like that approach, however, at the stage I am at I just need to see if "X" is dominant to "Y" at least 3 more times than "Y" is ever dominant to "X" which is why I wanted to sort the dataframe so that it shows the "freq" or number of occurences of "5" dominant to "9" right next to "9" dominant to "5" in the table but maybe there is a better way of doing this? Maybe an if-then statement?

Comment: Can you post a URL or text file with the full 321 entries maybe? I think the responses would probably be more spot on with a dataset containing examples of multiple occurrences of mutuals. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks @mysteRious ! I added it above!!